# Upload images to imgur account from shutter

Tags: shutter

I use [shutter](http://shutter-project.org/) for screenshots, it has an option to upload to imgur as a guest, is it possible to upload to my account instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the standard plugins, [this cannot currently be done](https://bugs.launchpad.net/shutter/+bug/990921).
It could be made possible but to date, nobody has sat down and written the required code.

The FTP section that Mitch is pointing to is for uploading to FTP servers and is separate from the Accounts section above it.

Comment: Three years later and still apparently nobody has...

Comment: This might be a good lesson why picking a layman-friendly language (eg Python) is a good idea for open source projects. Perl isn't *impossible* to grok but it's ugly enough to put me off.

Comment: It looks like this can be done now: https://imgur.com/RbXdDuh.png (it was hard taking a screenshot of the screenshooter...)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can upload to your own FTP.  Just add the information under Edit --> Preferences, and add it there.  See image below.

[image]

The FTP details are ISP dependent, just ask your ISP for that.  In may case as an example: `ftp://website.com/public_html/<folder_name>`. Folder name is where you want your images to go.  To choose FTP as the upload location, right click on the image --> export and then choose FTP.

[image]

You have to have a registered account with Imgur, and then check Authorized Upload, or OAuth Upload which means (The Imgur API uses OAuth 2.0 for authentication. OAuth 2.0 has four steps: registration, authorization, making the request, and getting new access_tokens after the initial one expired.)

[image]

Comment: I cannot turn the authorized upload to imgur, what are the ftp details?

Comment: See the addition in the answer.

Comment: but I'm trying to upload to http://imgur.com/